# Write .out file to csv file without column header in R

Tags: r

I am writing .out file (which has no header) to csv file but this code is taking the first line of data as a header. How to solve this issue.

```
files <- list.files(pattern="*.OUT")
newfiles <- gsub(".OUT$", ".csv")
file.rename(files, newfiles)
files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
print(files)
```

Comment: This code is not parsing the files at all. It's just renaming them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try both two methods below:

### 0. Use `write.table()`

```r
write.table(x, "yourfile.csv", col.names = TRUE)
```

### 1. Use faster and easier `fwrite()`

`fwrite()` comes with R package `data.table`, to use it, first:

```r
install.packages('data.table')
library(data.table)
```

And use this statement to save to file:

```r
fwrite(x, "yourfile.csv", col.names = TRUE)
```

`x` is the `data.frame` you wanna write to the file.